# How to pass a parameter in http get call on click a button in angular 11

Tags: angular

I have a simple http get call,I am calling an API and passing a parameter on load of a page. Now when I click on button, I only want to pass parameter without calling API for performance. Here is the code below  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fy7jyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  totalAngularPackages: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get<any>('https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.totalAngularPackages = data;
      });
  }
  changParam() {
    this.http
      .get<any>('https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/2')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.totalAngularPackages = data;
      });
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="changParam()">Change Param</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by this "Now when I click on button, I only want to pass parameter without calling API for performance" ? Do you want to call the api on init and button click or only on button click?

Comment: Pass parameter where? to `changParam` function or to api?

Comment: I think I got what you want. Do you want to filter employees in client side?

Comment: On load I want to call api passing parameter, that is fine. But on button click I want to get result only by passing parameter without unnecessary http call.

Comment: ok. Do you have the required data before button click ?

Comment: Yes when the page loads I am calling the API right, that is the required data before button click

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data given another employee identifier you need to make an HTTP call, or alternatively you gotta have all the JSON beforehand and then perform a search within the given object.

Depending on how big the JSON is maybe it's just going to be better to deal with 2 or 3 extra HTTP requests rather than having *A LOT* of unused data that is sitting there on the background.

Now, given your question, you may use the power of RxJS and string interpolation to change the data-source for your template something like this should suffice for your use-case:

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  currentlySelectedId = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  currentlySelectedId$ = this.currentlySelectedId.asObservable()
  currentEmployee$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     // We'll derivate the current employee from another data-source
     // our currently selected Id!
     this.currentEmployee$ = this.currentlySelectedId$.pipe(
       // Map the Id's received into the URL we want to query
       map(id => `https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/${id}`)
       // Now we want to return the result from another observable
       // that's what switchmap does!
       switchMap(url => this.http.get<any>(url))
     );
  }

  changParam() {
    // Emit a new Id value and the whole pipeline defined in the constructor
    // Will kick in and you'll have real-time updates!
    this.currentlySelectedId.next(2)
  }


}
```

```html
<!-- async subscribes and unsubscribes from the currentEmployee$ for you -->
<hello *ngIf="currentEmployee$ | async as employee" [name]="employee.name"></hello>
<button (click)="changParam()">Change Param</button>
```